# Is UPDATE command thread safe (tracking revisions) in MS SQL

Tags: sql, entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-6

Suppose we have a blog tool where each time a user performs a modification on an **Article(Id,Body,Revisions)**, the revision counter is incremented by 1. If we would execute the following query (in MS SQL), and, assuming that we have many people trying to update the article, would we then get the 'right' **Revisions**?

Since I'm using EF, I have expressed the query in the following way:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.Articles SET Revisions = Revisions + 1 WHERE Id=@p0;", articleId);
```

NB: What I mean by 'right' **Revisions** is that if we would have 100 people updating the article simultaneously, once they are all finished, the **Revisions** would be set to **100**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is thread-safe. The database engine will lock the record during the update, which means any other threads will have to wait for it to finish its update.

During that time the field will indeed increment with one, without any interference from other threads. Once done, the resource is unlocked, and the next waiting thread will lock it in turn, and do the same.

As explained in the [docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), the lock is an exclusive one:

> **Exclusive (X)**     Used for data-modification operations, such as INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE. Ensures that multiple updates cannot be made to the same resource at the same time.

and:

> **Exclusive Locks**
>   Exclusive (X) locks prevent access to a resource by concurrent transactions. No other transactions can read or modify data locked with an exclusive (X) lock.