# Specifying an upper bound for an int in UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

Given a table, for example **Article(Id,Body,Revisions)**, I would like to increment the Revisions attribute, and, once a certain limit is reached (it's a constant provided by the developer), an error should be thrown. Is this possible to achieve with a single UPDATE ... SET statement in T-SQL?

**What I've done:**

- To increment Revisions attribute by one, I solved as shown here: [Is UPDATE command thread safe (tracking revisions) in MS SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975139/is-update-command-thread-safe-tracking-revisions-in-ms-sql).

**Problem**

- To find a way that is thread safe, which would allow incrementation of **Revisions** until a certain upper bound is reached.

**Context**

Since I'm using EF, the ideal solution would be to either thrown an error or specify a flag of some sort. The code I'm using (shown below) is encapsulated into a try-catch:

```
 context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.Articles SET Revisions = Revisions + 1 WHERE Id=@p0;", articleId);
```

Comment: What kind of error I you thinking about? An exception by the database engine? Or do you have a programming environment that connects to the database engine that should trigger the error?

Comment: @trincot, Please see the updated "Context" section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` statement, which would do the test. If the test fails, the update will not happen and your call with `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` will return 0 instead of 1.

In case of a limit of 1000, the update SQL would be:

```
count = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
  "UPDATE dbo.Articles SET Revisions = Revisions + 1 WHERE Id=@p0 AND Revisions < 1000;", articleId);
```

Then afterwards you would test whether `count == 0` and raise an error message if so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This solution works perfectly for me! Maybe one minor drawback is that count=0 will be zero when the object does not exist too. However, it's not that important in my problem. Thanks again! :)

Comment: A different update statement could violate that upper bound.

Comment: Of course, this is the responsibility of the application.

Answer (score 2):

Use a CHECK constraint. No update statement can violate bounds that are implemented by a CHECK constraint. Not even an update statement issued by a sleep-deprived DBA at the console.

```
create table article (
   id integer primary key,
   body nvarchar(max) not null,
   -- Allow six versions. (Original plus five revisions.)
   revisions integer not null
      check (revisions between 0 and 5)
);

insert into article values (1, 'a', 0);

update article 
set body = 'b', revisions = 1 
where id = 1;

update article 
set body = 'c', revisions = 2 
where id = 1;

-- Other updates . . .

-- This update will *always* fail with an error.
update article
set body = 'f', revisions = 6 
where id = 1;
```

Comment: I think that in this case, the check constraint will force all values in the attribute Revisions to fulfill this condition. Is there any way to do this only for one row?

Comment: You can add a column `revision_limit` to the table, and change the constraint to `revisions between 0 and revision_limit`.  That gives you the ability to specify a separate revision limit for each row.  You can also add a boolean column `unlimited_revisions` to the table, and make the constraint `unlimited_revisions OR (revisions BETWEEN 0 and revision_limit)`

Comment: @Artem: Do you really want only one row to have a constraint on the number of revisions, or do you want each row to possibly have a different constraint on the number of revisions?  In either case, think about editing your question, and clarifying what you mean by *it's a constant provided by the developer*.

Comment: @Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall', Yes, I've used the revision id as a simplified example of a bigger problem. Anyways, thank you for your answer! :) It will work in solutions where someone wants to enforce this rule on all attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of whacked but

```
UPDATE dbo.Articles 
SET Revisions = Revisions + 1 
WHERE Id=@p0
AND sqrt(Revisions - @MaxRevisions - 2) >= 0;
```

If Revisions - @Revisions - 2 is negative it will throw an

> An invalid floating point operation occurred.

error

Comment: this is an interesting solution that uses mathematics to put the constrain I've described. I'm not really sure how SQL will figure out the SQRT, especially on large values, but it should work. +1.

Comment: @Artem What makes you think SQRT might fail on large number?   Per the documentation it will take anything that will cast to float  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176108.aspx

Comment: It's hard to say something without benchmarking or the implementation of SQRT, but I just get the feeling that throwing errors + use an external function (SQRT, how is it approximated, etc..) + cast between different types might add an overhead. However, in contrast to just adding 'AND Revisions < 1000', I think, but cannot claim, that it will be faster.

Comment: Yes overhead.  But it throws an error - if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, my specification must be vague. Anyway, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If the limit is 100,

```
UPDATE Article
SET Revisions = LEAST(Revisions + 1, 100)
where Id = @p0
```

Comment: will this throw an error of some kind in case Revisions +1 isg greater than 100?

Comment: No, it won't.  Sorry, I missed that requirement.