# SQL Server : incrementing non identity int column by procedure call

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in DB table which has to be increment when let's say some item is selected. But it can be selected parallel and for any records it has to start from 0. My solution is to increment the value from DB procedure, but can I be sure that the first procedure manages to increment the value before another procedure want to load the value to increment? I mean:

```
t0 Value is 10
t1 Procedure1 valueToInc = Value
t2 Procedure2 valueToInc = Value
t3 Procedure1 valueToInc ++
t4 Procedure2 valueToInc ++
t5 Value = 11
t6 Value = 11
```

Value written back from Procedure1 is 11 but from Procedure2 is obviously also 11 (need to secure 12 there).

I have also checked identity (property) and sequence (Transact-SQL) but nothing seems to be suitable for me.

**Edit**

What I´m trying to solve is that I have a console application - TCP server and MSSQL database, where I have a User table. Each time the single user wants to login, I have to increment users loginCount field. Any parallelization here should not be possible or is manageable from code, I know, but it was told me that I have to hande parallel acces by database, so not just to use update query. I have it as job interview project...

I wanted to make understanding easier by my first explanation, but it won´t work.

Comment: Are you saying you have a column and are constantly needing to change the value by adding 1 to it? An identity isn't going to help there. I have to say I have never heard of such a requirement. No matter what you do you will need to deal with concurrency which depending on what you are really trying to do may be pretty challenging.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I´m not sure if constantly is the right word but from time to time it could happend, that two accesess in one time will be neccesary to handle

Comment: Is the requirement to know how many times a row has been "selected"?  Literally selected or do you mean "picked" by the user to be used somewhere?   Or is this an optimistic concurrency tool?

Comment: I think the biggest issue at this point is that nobody knows what you are trying to do. Please try to explain what it is you are trying to do. Maybe an example table and an explanation of the process.

Comment: Thank you for comments, I tried to explain it better in Edit.

Comment: This is part of a job interview? You are being hired for your skills, not the collective knowledge of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use

```
UPDATE Users
SET LoginCount = ISNULL(LoginCount,0) + 1
WHERE UserId = @UserId
```

This is entirely safe under conditions of concurrency.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There it is nicely shown http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975139/is-update-command-thread-safe-tracking-revisions-in-ms-sql.

Answer (score 0):

Use a transaction with transaction isolation level equal to [`SERIALIZABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx).

> SERIALIZABLE
>
> - Statements cannot read data that has been modified but not yet committed by other transactions.
> - No other transactions can modify data that has been read by the current transaction until the current transaction completes.
> - Other transactions cannot insert new rows with key values that would fall in the range of keys read by any statements in the current transaction until the current transaction completes.

Don't load the `Value` to increment it: increment it, then select it (within the transaction). This will lock the table/row (depending) from updates/selects of other transactions.